# creating custom or modified url using router for retrive method of ModelViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I want to create a custom or modified url using router for ModelViewSet.

Current scenario:

**/models.py**

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, unique=True)
```

**/serializers.py**

```
class BlogListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        exclude = ('id',)
```

**/views.py**

```
class BlogViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogListSerializer
```

**/urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'blog', BlogViewSet, basename='blog')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Now, I can access the url as below:

list https://localhost:8000/blog

retrieve https://localhost:8000/blog/1

As You can see that the retrieve url can be called using the pk or id. 
But I have created a model field called slug and its unique. My question is that how do I modify the retrieve url so that I can call the retrieve url using the slug field. For example: https://localhost:8000/blog/test-slug

Note: Why do I want to create a url using slug?
Answer: I want to use the urls for sitemap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your api needs to return results by querying the slug field (and not the `pk` field) you could use the `lookup_field` and `lookup_url_kwarg` of DRF.

The `pk` or `id` field lookup is the default lookup and mentioned in DRF docs.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

views.py

```
class BlogViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogListSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'slug'
```

Comment: Exactly this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
# add a new url in your urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/<slug:slug>/', views.Blogdetail.as_view(), name='blog_detail'),
]



# In views.py define a class Blogdetail or make changes in the existing class

class Blogdetail(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogDetailsSerializer


    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.request.query_params.get("slug", None)
        if  slug == None:
            queryset = self.queryset
        else:
            queryset = self.queryset.filter(slug = slug)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Blogdetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogDetailsSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        slug = self.kwargs["slug"]
        obj = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
        return obj

class BlogUrlHyperlinkedIdentityField(serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField)

        def get_url(self, obj, view_name, request, format):
            kwargs = {
                "slug": obj.slug
            }
            return reverse(view_name, kwargs=kwargs, request=request, format=format)

class BlogListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = BlogUrlHyperlinkedIdentityField("blog_detail")
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
       fields = [
            "url",.....]
```

Add the url also

```
path('blog/<slug:slug>/', views.Blogdetail.as_view(), name='blog_detail'),
```